# How can I auto-generate unique fake names for users?

Tags: postgresql, alias, sequence, privacy

**We would like to give each of users an alias so that we can refer to them in discussions while protecting their identity.** These aliases should be unique.

The **easy way** would be to simply use a SERIAL column, but ints aren't memorable. We would like to use real people names so that we can remember the aliases.

The **other easy way** would be to find a list of first names somewhere, number them, and use a SERIAL to fetch names from the list. When the list runs out, add more names.

But is there some **clever way** to map ints to names?

We currently have about 2,000 users and are growing, but I doubt we'll ever become Google.

Comment: Why are you looking to have names and serial numbers? Many sites let people choose their own alias. Just detail what the alias is for and how it will be exposed, when the user picks it.

Comment: Good question! These aliases are for internal use (e.g. reporting research results). The users will never see them.

Answer (score 7):

It may sound crazy. But there is [an algorithm](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Generating_Names_Phonetically.shtml) used in game programming to create meaningless but phonetically unique names like  Alveolar, Bilabial, Glottal, Palatal, Velar.

Answer (score 5):

Pick a random name from [the Census Bureau's names file](http://www.census.gov/genealogy/names/names_files.html).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried any [Hash functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)? I am not sure whether they are available in Postgres. But yeah, one way to do is let the internal hash function take care. They will output unique IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Back in "the day" Compuserve (or was it AOL?) used to give out temporary, initial passwords by having two lists of words and taking one word from each list and putting it together, so you would get something like EasyTomato or whatever.  Perhaps something like that would work for your user base.  If each word list has 256 characters, that's 65535 unique combinations (and notice how easily you can pick the combination by just incrementing a 16-bit integer).

EDIT: Well don't do a straight increment of the integer after all, or the first 256 people will all get the same first word, but the basic idea is still sound.  Pick a random, not-yet-used 16-bit number.  High 8 bits are your index into the first word list, low 8 bits are your index into the second word list.